# EF 5 : OriginalValues are lost when context is disposed

Tags: wpf, frameworks, entity, dbcontext

I am novice in EF. So to test the optimistic concurrency I used EF 5,WPF and an already created database.The WPF project contains a `MainWindow` Having `TextBox1` for searching customer via primary key,`TextBox2` for customer's name edit,a `textblock (txtLog)` to log Field values and a save button. To simulate Concurrency access, in `SQL Server 2008` Management Studio i excute the query 
"`update client set r01_nomcli = 'GGGGG' where r01_codcli = '4112010002';`" 
before clicking on save Button. it works fine and `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is fired, but The original values of the entity were lost and take the same values 
as those of the current values. This is because of the "using" block which causes the detachment of the entities. To solve this problem, i have to declare the context just before the constructor of the window and instantiate it in "`Window_Loaded`" event
Is There another to make this ???
Helps about best practice of Using EF and how Building reusable DAL with EF 5 will be welcome.
Thanks.
Below the code :

```
 public partial class OptimisticConcurrency : Window
{

//client is an entity

    client _currentClient = null;

    public OptimisticConcurrency()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    //**************************TextBox1 PreviewKeyDown Event Handler
    private void TextBox_PreviewKeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {

            using (dbleaseEntities context = new dbleaseEntities())
            {
                _currentClient = context.client.Find(txtCode.Text);
                if (_currentClient == null)
                    MessageBox.Show("Customer " + txtCode.Text + " not found.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                else
                    this.DataContext = _currentClient;
            }
        }
    }


//*****************Save Button Click Event Handler

private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (dbleaseEntities context = new dbleaseEntities())
        {
            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            try
            {
                context.Entry(_currentClient).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
                MessageBox.Show("Success.", "Save", MessageBoxButton.OK,    MessageBoxImage.Information);
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                string ss = "";
                foreach (var error in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                    ss = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, error.ValidationErrors.Select(v => v.ErrorMessage));
                MessageBox.Show(ss, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
             }

            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                string StrValues= "";
                DbPropertyValues ov = ex.Entries.Single().OriginalValues;
                DbPropertyValues cv = ex.Entries.Single().CurrentValues;
                DbPropertyValues dv = ex.Entries.Single().GetDatabaseValues();

                StrValues=  "Original value  : " + ov["r01_nomcli"] + Environment.NewLine +
                            "Current value   : " + cv["r01_nomcli"] + Environment.NewLine +
                            "Database value  : " + dv["r01_nomcli"];

               txtLog.Text = StrValues



            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have roughly three options

1. Do what you're doing now - i.e. keep the object connected to context
2. Use self tracking entities: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/24/self-tracking-entities-in-the-entity-framework.aspx
3. Use GetDatabaseValues

Comment: for the first choice : if i keep context connected for a long time is it good or bad practice? it stuffs resources like RAM...

Comment: For the second choice, I am printing the article. But for the  choice 3 if you can clarify a little.

Comment: I don't think its a major concern for RAM, but its generally not a great idea to keep the context connected for a long time - how long are we talking? The main issues I see is that you may get some strange behavior if you have multiple instances of the context floating around for a while = the context caches some data, and its internal values will become invalid. There are other concerns around this, but it does depend on the specific application and its architecture

Comment: Choice 3 means you effectively go and fetch the values from the database and repopulate them

Comment: I think that In professional use ,the best way is to inform the user that the record which he are editing was modified by another user and display affected fields
and to give him the choice : 1°) keep changes Or 2°) overwrite  or 3°) cancel.

Comment: Don't give him the choice... use option 1 (keep changes) sliently or you may find two users keep overwriting and end up getting 2 complaints that your software keeps bugging them after they repeatingly instrcuted your app to overwrite with their changes..