# Get OriginalValues Entity Framework from an entity after the context is closed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i'm trying to retrive OriginalValues from a entity after the context has been closed, but i get CurrentValues. Any suggestion?
Can not get entity connected to the object, i must close it. Think about a generic model, the below one is just a sample.

To let you understaind, here my sample (as reference the db can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677.aspx)

```
public static void Sample1() 
{
    var blog = null;

    //1: get from context
    using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
    { 
        blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);
        //suppose -> blog.Name == "Test 1";
    }

    blog.Name = "Test 2"; //set name

    //The function here set the blog name record to "Test 3", using straight SQL
    SetBlogNameUsingExternalSQL("Test 3", 1);

    //2: get original values
    using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
    {
        context.Blogs.Attach(blog);
        var currentValues = context.Entry(blog).CurrentValues;
        //currentValues.Name is "Test 2", expected is "Test 2" => OK
        var databaseValues = context.Entry(blog).GetDatabaseValues(); 
        //databaseValues.Name is "Test 3", expected is "Test 3" => OK
        var originalValues = context.Entry(blog).OriginalValues;
        // -------> originalValues.Name is "Test 2", expected is "Test 1" => :(
    }
}
```

Note: this doesn't help me much: [EF 5 : OriginalValues are lost when context is disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871294/ef-5-originalvalues-are-lost-when-context-is-disposed)

Comment: `OriginalValues` is always stored for the current _context_, not globally. When the first context is disposed it no longer exists, so those `OriginalValues` are gone. The second context stores its `OriginalValues` as what is in the object when it is first attached to it, which is "Test 2". If you need access to "Test 1", you'll have to store it separate from any EF context.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, because of the way that the `DbContext` is responsible for maintaining original values, the second `DbContext` is simply unaware of them.

At a minimum, you will have to transfer these values yourself.

For example:

```
Blog blog = null;
DbPropertyValues originalBlogValues = null;

//1: get from context
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);
    originalBlogValues = context.Entry(blog).OriginalValues;
}

blog.Name = "Test 2";

using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{
    context.Blogs.Attach(blog);
    context.Entry(blog).OriginalValues.SetValues(originalBlogValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. "...The problem is that, because ... them..." This is the thing i would like to ear. Indeed i already do something like you said, I store original values on a temporary variable, but i would like to have a confirmation about my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

As Rhumborl and Jean Hominal reply, `OriginalValues` is always stored in the loaded context, and are disposed with the context. So a proposed solution could be to store original values within the first context creation.

```
var originalValues = null;

//1: get from context
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    blog = context.Blogs.Find(1);
    //suppose -> blog.Name == "Test 1";
    originalValues = context.Entry(blog).OriginalValues; //load OriginalValues here
}
```